# MS Access, number formatting

Tags: ms-access, numbers

I need to display a number (real), ie 1234.567 like "1.234,56" or "1,234.56". I know that I have to use Format() but I can't figure it out.
 (It's for a textbox where the 'Control Source' property is set to some number field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* do it:

```
Format(number, "#,##0.00")
```

Where the actual separators used depend on the current locale setting.

Comment: Since I can't currently find the according MSDN page, here a nice 3rd party documentation of Format(): http://www.apostate.com/vb-format-syntax

Comment: Hm... was not so hard to find, after all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262745(VS.60).aspx ... It's just not very helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: There is another link that might be helpful. It contains MS ACCESS user defined numeric formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fb56f4y(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I am trying to use "#,###.##" in the textbox's Format property but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to use the VBA Format() function. In the Access UI textbox property, the decimal and thousands separators are locale-specific as well. Using "#.##0,00" may be worth a try. In any case this specific format is named "Standard", so putting in the word "Standard" into the property should work as well. Pressing F1 when you are in the "Format" property field fires up the help, which has good guidance to offer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below method worked for me in ms access 2000-2003. 
You should make changed in Table and in reports.
Table.
Go to the required field, Change data type to Nnmber, Field size to Decimal, Format to Standard.

Report.
Select the control where you want the thousand separator, select properties the format Select standard,, Decimal places 2.